# Ronald and the traffic lights

Tags: lateral-thinking, knowledge

Every time his car stopped at a traffic light, Ronald would move to get out, then realize that he did not want to get out.
What was going on?

Hints:

> He was a famous person.
> He was being driven by someone.
> He was free to leave when he wished.

**BIG HINT**

> Ronald was a real person (who was, incidentally, called Ronald.... He was extremely famous).

Comment: I think there would a vast number of valid solutions for this question apart from the intended one. Suggesting to narrow it down some more.

Comment: An example of some valid yet likely not what you are looking for answers, Ronald isn't paying attention and continuously thinks he has arrived at his destination, or he is in a taxi and keeps considering getting out and walking, then remembers he is rich(due to being famous) so stays in the taxi

Comment: Another example would be: Its raining cats and dogs and he does not want to spoil his Armani suit.

Comment: Ronald could also be a famed veteran and his instinct when a vehicle stops is to get out (Disclaimer: I have never been in the military but this seems plausible)

Comment: Sounds like Ron Howard to me

Comment: Is this related to the assassination attempt against Ronald Reagan?

Comment: Not sure about the real-life tag; this is the only question with that tag. I think the "knowledge" tag would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Ronald in question is:

> Ronald Reagan

because...

> As President, he was chauffeured around, and the only time his car would stop is when it reached the destination. Old habits die hard, and eight years of this habit carried on with him afterwards.

Answer (score 8):

Is Ronald:

> Not sure how to say it in english but in a car on a  Carousel, Whirligig or Merry-go-round?

Every time his car stopped at a traffic light,

> The stop light of the carousel when it stops/is standing still.

Ronald would move to get out, then realize that he did not want to get out.

> Ronald wants to keep spinning on the carousel, because yeay carousels!

HINTS:

> He was a famous person. Mr Carousel? (unsure about this)
>  He was being driven by someone.  It spins by the operator.
>  He was free to leave when he wished.  He can leave the carousel when he wants.

Comment: Never heard of whirligig before, gave me a chuckle. Solid lateral thinking answer, but who knows what the asker was looking for haha. +1

Comment: Good thinking! I added a hint that should narrow things down quite a bit..

Answer (score 2):

Ronald is:

> Ronald McDonald

Who is displaying this behavior because:

> He's being driven by Grimace to yet another ad shoot where he's expected to put on yet another happy face and wolf down yet another cheeseburger.  All clowns are depressed (it is known) but on this particular day Ronald's despair is at an all-time low.  Not only is his Type II diabetes acting up, but just this morning he received a ransom note from the Hamburglar, saying he's abducted the Fry Kids and the only way to get them back is to solve some sort of puzzle with a cipher, Vigenere something, agar man, whatever.  Meanwhile, Grimace is going on at length about getting ketchup stains out of purple fur, interjecting his customary "duhs" before each "thought", and Ronald can tell that it's only a matter of time before Grimace tells that godawful joke about the frog who worked at McDonald's for the 1000th time.  ("Do you want flies with that?")  Ronald's quick search of the back seat of the company car turns up no weapons or other means of ending his misery, and he feels a familiar panic—belied by his hair—set in.  Every time the car slows down, every fiber of his being—and the considerable levels of LDL coursing through his body—scream at him to run for it.  Head into the desert and leave it all behind.  But just as the car slows, he remembers that Mayor McCheese has vowed to keep an eye on Ronald until the unpleasant Monopoly-embezzlement business has been sorted out, and reaching for the door he sees Officer BigMac's cruiser following them out of the corner of his eye, and feels hope drain from his body, and as he sinks deeper into the cushions and resigns himself to his fate, he reaches for his red face paint and begins to paint on a smile.
>
>  Obviously.

Answer (score 1):

Ronald had just bought a Toyota Prius. Every time the car stopped at a light the engine would turn itself off (that's how Priuses work), and Ronald, having been conditioned by many years of being driven around in non-hybrid vehicles, would be jerked out of his reverie about last night's party with other famous people thinking that the quiet signifies that the car had arrived at its destination.

Answer (score -2):

> Ronald is Ronald Reagan, who had Alzheimer's disease.

Comment: I'm curious about the down votes here. This answer was posted before the accepted one, so I wouldn't think that they are for duplication, it would be nice if the reasoning was explained so that I could improve.